# sqlalchemy inconsistent row updates

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

each of the following functions fails to update the record ~10% of the time. What am I not understanding about sqlalchemy?  THANKS!

```
def update_field_1 ( session, rec ):
    rec.field1 = 'hello'
    session.merge(rec)
    return

def update_field_2 ( session, rec ):        
    session.query( TableName ).filter( TableName.id==rec.id )\
        .update( {"field2": "hello"} )
    return

# create conn/session
# create record
session.add( record )
session.commit()

update_field_1 ( session, record )
update_field_2 ( session, record )

session.commit()
# close session/conn
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this mystery with my own testing.  Posting here to help anyone searching...

The code was a bit simplified.  We really see something more like this:

```
if something:
    session.add( record )
    session.commit()
else:
    session.rollback()

if something_else:
    update_field_1 ( session, record )
    update_field_2 ( session, record )
else:
    session.rollback()
```

Spot the error?  Need the first function to do something like this:

```
session.merge( rec )
session.commit()
```

The second case, will fail if the add commit doesn't happen and there's no id in the session.